# Calculating bias of ML estimate of AR(1) coefficient

Tags: estimation, autoregressive, bias-correction

I am trying to develop adjustment factors for maximum-likelihood estimates of the auto-regression coefficient in an AR(1) process. By simulation I have discovered that the estimates are positively biased but consistent. I would like to produce a table of bias factors by number of observations N in the time series and population coefficient, which I would then try to convert into a table of correction factors by N and estimate value.

Looking at related posts on here I see confirmation that the estimate is biased and consistent, and there is a formula for the asymptotic variance. there is also a thread about the bias from using MA(1) to approximate AR(1). But I could not find any formula for the bias of a MLE estimate of teh AR(1) coefficient.

If no formula is available, I can use simulation to produce my table. But I would rather do it analytically if possible. The estimator is:

$$\hat\theta = \frac{\sum_t y_t y_{t-1}}{\sum_t y_{t-1}{}^2}$$

where $\theta$ is the AR coefficient and $y_1,...,y_N$ are the observed time series values. What I am looking for is how to calculate $E[\hat\theta]$ in terms of $\theta$ and $N$. For the time series I am working with, the instantaneous volatility $\sigma$ is always 1.

Any suggestions on how I could develop a formula for $E[\hat\theta]$, $E[\hat\theta] - \theta$ or $E[\hat\theta]/\theta$ would be gratefully received. Ditto if you can advise that there is no known solution, in which case I will just proceed to use simulation.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for de-biasing the estimator? De-biasing may lead to higher variance, and so your expected squared error may increase. In other words, de-biasing may make the estimator all too noisy so that in practice you would rather have some bias with a decent precision in place of no bias and awful precision. Personally, I do not think de-biasing this estimator is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Richard. The de-biasing approach I have in mind is multiplying the estimate by a correction factor that is independent of the observations, similar to how a sample variance - the ML estimator of population variance - is converted to an unbiased estimate of population variance by multiplying by n/(n-1). If that is possible, it will slightly decrease estimator variance because the correction factor will be slightly less than 1.

Comment: Perhaps relevant (especially the beginning of the paper): Reschenhofer ["Heteroscedasticity-robust estimation of autocorrelation"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03610918.2017.1408826) (2019).

Answer (score 3):

For this type of estimate, it is quite difficult to get a useful expression for the distribution of the estimator, and hence, for the expected value.  The behaviour of the estimator can be related back to a normal quadratic form, but this gives quite a complicated expression.

---

**Distribution of the times series vector:** Suppose we use the centered $\text{AR}(1)$ model $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ with homoscedastic normal error terms and $|\phi|<1$ for stationarity.  We can write the distribution of the observable time series vector $\mathbb{y} = (y_1,...,y_n)$ as:

$$\mathbf{y} \sim \text{N}( \mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}(\phi)) \quad \quad \quad
\mathbf{\Sigma}(\phi) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}  
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & \phi & \phi^2 & \cdots & \phi^{n-2} & \phi^{n-1} \\
\phi  & 1 & \phi & \cdots & \phi^{n-3} & \phi^{n-2} \\
\phi^2 & \phi & 1 & \cdots & \phi^{n-4} & \phi^{n-3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\phi^{n-2} & \phi^{n-3} & \phi^{n-4} & \cdots & 1 & \phi \\
\phi^{n-1} & \phi^{n-2} & \phi^{n-3} & \cdots & \phi & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Taking the [principal square root of the variance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) gives the alternative form:

$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) \mathbf{z} \quad \quad \quad
\mathbf{z} \sim \text{N}( \mathbf{0},\boldsymbol{I}) \quad \quad \quad
\mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) = \mathbf{\Sigma}(\phi)^{1/2}.$$

(The matrix $\mathbf{\Delta}(\phi)$ can easily be obtained using the Eigendecomposition of the variance matrix.  The variance matrix and its square root are [symmetric circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), with fixed  eigenvector matrix equal to the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) and eigenvalues that are functions of $\phi$.)

---

**Distribution of the OLS estimator:** For this model (clarifying your use of subscripts in the sums) the OLS estimator is:

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_t y_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^n y_t^2}.$$

(Note that the OLS estimator for this model is not equal to the MLE estimator, since it effectively ignores a logarithmic term involving the variance matrix that is in the likelihood function.)  To find the distribution of the OLS estimator, define the $n \times n$ matrix:

$$\mathbf{M}(r) \equiv \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & r & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & r & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & r & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & r \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

It can be shown that the event $\hat{\theta} \leqslant r$ is equivalent to the event $\mathbb{y}^\text{T} M(r) \mathbb{y} \geqslant 0$, so we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F_\hat{\theta}(r) 
\equiv \mathbb{P}(\hat{\theta} \leqslant r) 
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{y}^\text{T} \mathbf{M}(r) \mathbb{y} \geqslant 0) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}((\mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) \mathbf{z})^\text{T} \mathbf{M}(r) (\mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) \mathbf{z}) \geqslant 0) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) \mathbf{M}(r) \mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) \mathbf{z} \geqslant 0) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{H}(\phi, r) \mathbf{z} \geqslant 0), \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where $\mathbf{H}(\phi, r) \equiv \mathbf{\Delta}(\phi) \mathbf{M}(r) \mathbf{\Delta}(\phi)$.  Hence, the OLS estimator has the density function:

$$f_\hat{\theta}(r) = P_2(\phi,r) 
\quad \quad \quad
P(\phi,r) \equiv \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{H}(\phi, r) \mathbf{z} \geqslant 0). $$

Thus, the expected values is $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = \int \limits r P_2(\phi,r) dr$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer Ben. It looks like it may be just what I need. It will take a while for me to work through it. I will respond further when I have managed to do that.

Comment: I think there is a problem here. Shouldn't you have $E(y_t y_{t+k}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1- \phi^2} \phi^k$ as elements in $\Sigma(\phi)$?

Comment: Thanks --- corrected.